# Get every possible set of pairs from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a PHP script where I have two arrays of ID's. I need to generate every possible set that can be created by pairing the ID's from the two arrays. Each set needs to contain pairings for every ID.

I'm currently using three nested `for` loops, and as long as I only have three items in each array, this seems to generate the desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => A
            [2] => C
            [3] => B
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => A
            [2] => B
            [3] => C
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => B
            [2] => A
            [3] => C
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
            [3] => A
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => C
            [2] => B
            [3] => A
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => C
            [2] => A
            [3] => B
        )

)
```

However, if I go up to 4 items in each array, I can tell some combinations are missing. I also get some duplicate sets, which I can live with in this case, but still isn't ideal. I suspect this relates to my `for` loops only going 3 deep and that I should actually be using recursion here, but recursion very rarely comes up for the type of work I do and I haven't been able to pin down how to implement it effectively to return the needed results for this particular situation.

Here is my current code:

```
$first = array(1, 2, 3, 4,);
$second = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',);

$len = count($second);

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
    // Loop through positions
    for ($pos = 1; $pos < ($len - 1); ++$pos) {
        // Rotate loop
        $second_fixed = array_slice($second, 0, $pos);
        $second_rotate = array_slice($second, $pos);
        $second_rotate_len = count($second_rotate);

        for ($k = 0; $k < $second_rotate_len; ++$k) {
            $second_rotate[] = array_shift($second_rotate);
            $second = array_merge($second_fixed, $second_rotate);

            $set = array_combine($first, $second);
            $alternates[] = $set;
        }
    }

    $second[] = array_shift($second);
}

print_r($alternates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do for now.  Will need tweaking if arrays are not the same length.

```
$first = array(1, 2, 3, 4,);
$second = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',);

foreach($first as $f) {
    $result[] = array_combine($first, $second);
    $s = array_shift($second);
    $second[] = $s;
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This was my first thought, too, but simple rotation only generates every pairing -- not every set of pairings. For example, it generates 1B 2C 3D 4A, but can not generate 1B 2D 3C 4A.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an algorithm (or pseudo-code) that generates **all permutations of a list**, and then adapt that. That's essentially what you're doing here.